# Finding case-insensitive emails does not work in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Based from the config below in `initializers/devise.rb`:

`# Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]`

What does ***"find a user"*** mean? Is it when doing:

`User.find_by(email: "UsEr@ExampLe.com")`

Because that does not work and returns nil when I have a user with email `"user@example.com"` in the database.

Im using rails 5 and Devise 4.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `User.find_by(email: params[:email])` is case sensitive. Use `User.find_for_authentication(email: params[:email])` instead. See [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-case-insensitive-emails)

Comment: That works. Didn't see the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-case-insensitive-emails). Thanks!